# AVS with Alexa Skills

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, avs

Is it possible to use Alexa Skill with Alexa Voice Service (AVS)?

I can't find any AVS API to link to user's Amazon account to enable certain Skills. Is it possible that to use Skill on a third party Alexa device?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for.

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/alexa-voice-service/setup-authentication.html

Alexa isn't Alexa without skills, and AVS essentially just allows Alexa to work on devices that Amazon didn't create.

Once you create your third-party Alexa-enabled device, choose the best option from that documentation to allow users to authenticate with their Amazon account, allowing access to the skills they have chosen to enable.

So, yes, (hypothetically) anything that is possible on an Amazon Alexa-enabled device will be possible on a third-party Alexa-enabled device. :)

Edit:

Similar topic - [Alexa skill kit vs Alexa Voice Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994082/alexa-skill-kit-vs-alexa-voice-service)