# Can not exchange SMAPI token

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-voice-service

I created custom Alexa Skill with Schedule Appointment template. I want to use my Skill from our website. I think to place  tag on our frontend and pass POST /v2/skills/{skillId}/stages/{stage}/invocations to invoke my skill. Through ask-cli i generate my access token and refresh token. My access token has expired and i can`t get new one.

The doc https://developer.amazon.com/de-DE/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html page poins to https://developer.amazon.com/docs/login-with-amazon/retrieve-token-other-platforms-cbl-docs.html for refreshing token process.

I used Post https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token with client_id and client_secret from my Security Profile`s Web Settigs tab, but the response is 400 Bad Request "error_description": "Not authorized for requested operation"; if i set Authorization Bearer header with my expired token my response is 401 Unauthorized "error_description": "Client authentication failed".

Can you explain how to recive a new access token?
I read [Alexa skill kit vs Alexa Voice Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40994082/alexa-skill-kit-vs-alexa-voice-service) and may be Alexa skills is not suitable for web site and i need to prefer Alexa Voice Service?

Comment: Can you paste your request you sent to LWA without sensitive information? I'd also make sure you followed https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/get-access-token-smapi.html#both-resource-owner-and-client

Comment: Thank you, I don't use Alexa anymore. I don't understand how to implement Alexa on the frontend JavaScript to working with Alexa in PC`s browser.  The warning "Alexa Voice Service (AVS) developer tools are no longer generally available for Alexa Built-in" and archived smart screen web components repository waring "Please note, the AVS Device Software Development Kit is no longer being maintained." are confused me that Alexa is working in PC`s web browser.  Support from https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/contact-us has not answered me.